# Bug ao fazer INSERT no banco de dados com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho um script de INSERT que mesmo não selecionando nenhuma imagem dentro de outro input, no banco de dados salva o nome da imagem formatado pela função rand mas sem extensão alguma, em vez de ser vazio.

```
<?php
session_start();
    require_once "classes/conexao.php";
    require_once "classes/logar.php";
    ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
    require_once 'dbconfig.php';

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])):

        if($_GET['logout']== 'ok'):
           Login::deslogar();

    endif;

endif;
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
        $sub_titulo = $_POST['sub_titulo'];
        $texto_1 = $_POST['texto_1'];
        $texto_2 = $_POST['texto_2'];
        $texto_3 = $_POST['texto_3'];
        $texto_4 = $_POST['texto_4'];
        $categoria_1 = $_POST['categoria_1'];
        $categoria_2 = $_POST['categoria_2'];
        $categoria_3 = $_POST['categoria_3'];
        $autor = $_POST['autor'];

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];

        $imgFile2 = $_FILES['user_image2']['name'];
        $tmp_dir2 = $_FILES['user_image2']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize2 = $_FILES['user_image2']['size'];

        $imgFile3 = $_FILES['user_image3']['name'];
        $tmp_dir3 = $_FILES['user_image3']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize3 = $_FILES['user_image3']['size'];

        if(empty($titulo)){
            $errMSG = "Por favor Insira o Titulo";
        }

        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Selecione a imagem.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'img/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt =  strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $imgExt2 = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile2,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            $imgExt3 = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile3,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
      $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
            $userpic2 = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt2;
            $userpic3 = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt3;


            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Imagem muito grande.";
                }
            }
            else{

            }
            if(in_array($imgExt2, $valid_extensions)){          
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize2 < 5000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir2,$upload_dir.$userpic2);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Banner muito grande.";
                }
            }
            else{

            }
            if(in_array($imgExt3, $valid_extensions)){          
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize3 < 5000000)             {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir3,$upload_dir.$userpic3);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "IMAGEM 3 muito grande.";
                }
            }
            else{

            }

        }
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO posts (titulo,sub_titulo,texto_1,texto_2,texto_3,texto_4,categoria_1,categoria_2,categoria_3,autor,img1,img2,img3) VALUES(:utitulo,:usub_titulo,:utexto_1,:utexto_2,:utexto_3,:utexto_4,:ucategoria_1,:ucategoria_2,:ucategoria_3,:uautor,:upic,:upic2, :upic3)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':utitulo',$titulo);
            $stmt->bindParam(':usub_titulo',$sub_titulo);
            $stmt->bindParam(':utexto_1',$texto_1);
            $stmt->bindParam(':utexto_2',$texto_2);
            $stmt->bindParam(':utexto_3',$texto_3);
            $stmt->bindParam(':utexto_4',$texto_4);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ucategoria_1',$categoria_1);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ucategoria_2',$categoria_2);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ucategoria_3',$categoria_3);
            $stmt->bindParam(':uautor',$autor);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic2',$userpic2);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic3',$userpic3);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "Post adicionada com sucesso ...";
                header("refresh:3;painel_posts.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }

if(isset($_SESSION['logado'])):
else:
    header("Location: login.php");
endif;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="cairoodev">

  <title>Adicionar Post</title>

  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Page Wrapper -->
  <div id="wrapper">
  <?php
    include "nav_admin.php";
  ?>

        <!-- Begin Page Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">

          <!-- Page Heading -->
          <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Adicionar novo Post</h1>

          </div>
          <?php
    if(isset($errMSG)){
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
            </div>
            <?php
    }
    else if(isset($successMSG)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
              <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Titulo</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo do post" value="<?php echo $titulo; ?>" />
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Sub Titulo</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sub_titulo" placeholder="Sub Titulo do post" value="<?php echo $sub_titulo; ?>" />
                     </div>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label">Imagem Principal</label>
                <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image" accept="image/*" />
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Texto 1</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="texto_1" placeholder="Texto de introdução" value="<?php echo $texto_1; ?>" /></textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Texto 2</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="texto_2" placeholder="Texto de desenvolvimento" value="<?php echo $texto_2; ?>" /></textarea>   
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Texto 3</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="texto_3" placeholder="Texto de desenvolvimento 2" value="<?php echo $texto_3; ?>" /></textarea>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-6">
                     <label class="control-label">Texto 4</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="texto_4" placeholder="Texto de conclusão" value="<?php echo $texto_4; ?>" /></textarea>
                     </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Imagem 2</label>
                        <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image2" accept="image/*" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="control-label">Imagem 3</label>
                        <input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image3" accept="image/*" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label">Categorias</label>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria_1" placeholder="Categoria 1" value="<?php echo $categoria_1; ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria_2" placeholder="Categoria 2" value="<?php echo $categoria_2; ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">

                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="categoria_3" placeholder="Categoria 3" value="<?php echo $categoria_3; ?>"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="autor" placeholder="Autor" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nome'];?>"/>
            </div>
</div><br>
        <button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-primary shadow-sm">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span><i class="fas fa-download fa-sm text-white-50"></i> Postar
        </button>
    </form> 

          <!-- Content Row -- >

      </div>
      <!-- End of Main Content -->

      <!-- Footer -->
      <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white">
        <div class="container my-auto">
          <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
            <span>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2019</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
      <!-- End of Footer -->

    </div>
    <!-- End of Content Wrapper -->

  </div>
  <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->

  <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>

  <!-- Logout Modal-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Select "Logout" below if you are ready to end your current session.</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Nesse código quando seleciono a Imagem 1 apenas, no banco de dados fica assim.

[image: Banco de Dados]

dentro das colunas img2 e img3 em vez de ficar NULL ou vazio, fica com o valor do nome da imagem convertido e insere no banco sem as extensões.

Queria ajuda de como corrigir isso e quando eu inserir apenas uma imagem os outros campos de imagem não atribua nenhum valor.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de fazer os tratamentos de cada imagem verifique se a mesma existe.

Na primeira imagem você verifica isso, porem nas outras duas não.
else if(empty($imgFile)){
   $errMSG = "Selecione a imagem.";
}

Abs.